# Откуда в последовательности Фибоначчи отрицательное число?

Tags: java, числа-фибоначчи

Всех приветствую!
Нахожу последовательность Фибоначчи с помощью рекурсии

```
public class Main {

    static int fib(int n) {
        if (n == 1 || n == 2) return 1;
        return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) System.out.println(fib(i));
    }
}
```

Вот часть результата:

```
267914296
433494437
701408733
1134903170
1836311903
-1323752223
512559680
```

Кто-нибудь может объяснить откуда здесь отрицательное число и как вывести остальные числа на экран после 1836311903? Я поменял тип данных на long, но результат не изменился. Используемая IDE NetBeans.

Comment: И конечно же это не последовательность фибонначи, тут же сумма чисел фибонначи. Переполнение гарантировано :).

Comment: Нет, это не сумма чисел Фибоначчи, это и есть [числа Фибоначчи](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8)

Comment: Крутой спор. Увы, числа Фиббоначи по определению -- сумма чисел Фиббоначи.

Comment: @alexlz только не всех, а только двух предыдущих чисел (количество кроликов включая папу и маму)

Comment: Улыбнуло... и опечалило, ибо if you understand math jokes, you probably have no friends :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это чистое переполнение регистров `int`, максимальное целое число в терминах Java это `2^31-1=2.147.483.647`

чтобы работало корректно, надо не только параметр менять на `long`, но и возвращаемое значение:

```
static long fib(long n) { 
    if (n == 1 || n == 2) return 1; 
    return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1); 
}
```

а если и этого не хватит то есть еще и `BigInteger`

Comment: @Barmaley, но параметр зачем к long'у?:) Если нам нужен номер последовательности такой, что вписывается в long, то тут не одного типа не хватит для результата

Comment: @stck - да, параметр `long` это слишком, согласен...

Comment: Ребята, спасибо. Буду использовать long и учиться работать с BigInteger.

Answer (score 5):

Ну отрицательные - из-за переполнения типа.
Всё-таки стоит использовать long:

```
public static long fib(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return n;
    else return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

Но на 97 элементе - снова переполнение, но уже типа long. И рекурсивно считает он ооочень долго.

```
42: 267914296
43: 433494437
44: 701408733
45: 1134903170
46: 1836311903
47: 2971215073
СБОРКА ОСТАНОВЛЕНА (общее время: 2 минуты 1 секунда)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ох уж эта Java :)   как меня воротит от этого синтаксического мусора )

Ну а если серьезно, то тут стоит добавить, чтобы Вы также кешировали результаты вычислений. Представляете сколько одних и тех же вычислений делает программа?
Если какая-либо часть последовательности уже вычислена, то не нужно ее снова вычислять.

На примере JS, максимально подробно:

```
function fib(x){ 
    if(x < 3) 
        return 1;

    return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2);
}
```

Глядя на это в рабочем проекте, можно сказать, что кодеру воооообще не хотелось заниматься оптимизацией. Вот так, с КЕШем, будет гораздо, гораздо, гораздо быстрее:

```
var fibCache = {}; 
function fib(x){ 
    if(fibCache[x])
        return fibCache[x];

    if(x < 3)
        return 1;

    var val = fib(x-1) + fib(x-2);

    if(!fibCache[x])    
        fibCache[x] = val;

    return val; 
}
```

Теперь как пуля! )

Answer (score 1):

У вас действительно переполнение идет. Выводите в стринге, если хотите сколь угодно длинные числа получать. Работа с большими числами - отдельная тема.
ну, или "бейте" на порции, впрочем, опять к теме "большие числа" :)

"Ребята, спасибо. Буду использовать long и учиться работать с BigInteger."
тип long тут временный кастыль, на самом деле.
надо учиться не с сурогатными типом работать а с большими числами вообще.
Правда, они ни так часто нужны, но все же, вдруг вы криптографией занимаетесь ;)

Answer (score 0):

При вызове подпрограммы надо задавать начальное значение, а не подставлять мусор